# codeigniter - Form validation required file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

UPDATE : I solve my problem just add  to my form.
I use Codeigniter2  and use have problem with form validation

if form have text input  and uploadfile input  it work fine by this code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user','User','required');
if (empty($_FILES["image"]["name"]))
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('image','ไฟล์','required');
}
```

....

```
<input type="text" name="user" size="20" />
<input type="file" name="image" size="20" />
```

**but if I have only uploadfile input.**

```
<input type="file" name="image" size="20" />
```

the code in validation_run is not work. For example, `if($this->form_validation->run() == true){redirect('home');}` 
it will not redirect to home.  but the validation error message work normally. 
How should I do?

Comment: Did you load codeigniter `upload` library.

Comment: I have loaded library already.  as I said if my form have text input it work fine!

Comment: I solve my problem  just add <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="foo"/> to my form